# Error correcting tags

Tags: support, retagging

While trying to correct the tags for [this question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-are-short-and-long-form-adjectives-used-differently), I got the following error

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because: You are attempting to
>   create the tag long-form-adjectives ; however the tag
>   longformadjectives already exists! You are attempting to create the
>   tag short-form-adjectives ; however the tag shortformadjectives
>   already exists!

That doesn't seem right.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118027/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-hyphen-on-a-already-existing-tag-r2d2-r2-d2

Comment: We don't have moderators yet, though

Comment: @defaultlocale can you make this into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've flagged for moderator attention on this issue before I saw it mentioned here. I believe some SE staff act as moderators during the "nursery" stage of new SE sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118027/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-hyphen-on-a-already-existing-tag-r2d2-r2-d2) of the same problem on Meta.SO:

> Moderators can create a tag through the tag synonym interface. I declared r2-d2 as a synonym of r2d2, then merged r2d2 into r2-d2, and presto, the tag has been renamed

So as soon as we have moderators they should be able to create hyphenized tag synonym

Comment: We have at least three moderators (with rhombus) that are active on this site.